# What is this 20ft tall vine-like trunk?

Tags: identification, vines

This is in Central Texas and looks to have been topped off at some point.  The vines converge into the ground at its base. Apologies for the obstructed image. [image]

Comment: Ugh, Please! send another picture.  One where we are able to see the foliage, the stems...have you seen the flowers that this vine produces?  Any Kiwi's in your yard?  Just not enough to use to ID, sorry.

Comment: It looks dead- no flowers, no foliage, no growing stems

Comment: "It looks dead" - why is that a problem? ;)

Comment: Is there any indication of life?  Green buds? Greenish stems?  Most of this plant is dead.  Please look for green on these stems.  One can easily (?) clone or resurrect a plant like this.  Plants do have life time limits.  Old age and then death. This could be a very very mature honeysuckle or a Wisteria?